# Can we sneak into informations of RAM allocation

Tags: ram, ram-usage

I know that operating systems manipulate RAM and give programs their share of space.

My question is how Ubuntu remembers the allocations that it gives to programs. Is it some kind of table, and can we access that table and read its content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my knowledge, there is no way to check specific applications' permanently dedicated ram, however using system monitor or `htop,` you can check ram usage, and set priorities.

The install of `htop` is basic and much like any other, just `sudo apt-get install htop,` or use any package manager to install.

Then either run `htop` to view tasks on just your user account, and files on user accounts you have shared access to, or use `sudo htop` to view all running process on your machine.

As far as I know, the way Ubuntu allocates memory to a process is storing it in a file somewhere in the installation, as a priority, rather than an integer itself. If the program itself allocates "X amount of RAM," it will be sent as a specialized request to the system.

Imagine, however, that you have two programs running, both wanting to allocate, let's say 12 GB of RAM. If you have 16 GB, this cannot be done (obviously,) so the higher ***priority*** program will take the 12 GB. If both are of equal priority, the memory will be split between, leaving a fair bit out for system processes.

The System Monitor can also be used to set priority:

[image]

Hope this helps!